# How to remove row wise sorting in R dataframes

Tags: r

I have the following code written to take bind two columns and create a data frame.

```
complete<-function(directory,id){
  x<-vector()
  y<-vector()
  files<-list.files(directory,full.names=TRUE)
  for(i in id){
    x[i]<-i
    y[i]<-sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files[i])))
  }
  d<-na.omit(data.frame(x,y))
  colnames(d)<-c("id","nobs")
  rownames(d)<-1:nrow(d)
  print(d)
}
```

I have the following test case :

```
complete("specdata",30:25)
  id nobs
1 25  463
2 26  586
3 27  338
4 28  475
5 29  71
6 30  932
```

I am not able get the output in the order called by the function. i.e. 
id=30 as the first value and id=25 as the last value. How do I get to disable automatic sorting by id?

Answer (score 1):

We can change `for(i in id)` to `for(i in seq_along(id))` to loop by the sequence of 'id'.  Also, make some necessary changes in assigning `x[i]` and `y[i]`.

```
complete<-function(directory, id){
  x<- vector()
  y<- vector()
  files<-list.files(directory,full.names=TRUE)
  for(i in seq_along(id)){
   x[i]<- id[i]
   y[i]<-sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files[id[i]])))
 }
 d<-na.omit(data.frame(x,y))
 colnames(d)<-c("id","nobs")
rownames(d)<-1:nrow(d)
print(d)
}
```

Testing

```
 complete('specdata', 25:30)
#id nobs
#1 25    4
#2 26    0
#3 27    1
#4 28    1
#5 29    2
#6 30   13


complete('specdata', 30:25)
#  id nobs
#1 30   13
#2 29    2
#3 28    1
#4 27    1
#5 26    0
#6 25    4
```

NOTE: The values are different because the 'specdata' directory that I have is from a previous coursera link.  They might have updated the data